# Joomla 3.8 deploy to Heroku HTTP 500 error

Tags: php, http, heroku, joomla

I'm currently trying to deploy a new Joomla installation to Heroku.
I transferred all the files from the Joomla ZIP to the Git repo linked to my Heroku project, and I'm not encountering a HTTP 500 error when opening the website.
In the Heroku logs I can see the following errors pop up:

```
2018-03-27T09:17:48.900244+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
path="/" host=pacific-badlands-52973.herokuapp.com request_id=71491c3a-    62df-4054-b015-02d01bd8a073 fwd="94.143.189.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms     service=8ms status=500 bytes=169 protocol=https
2018-03-27T09:17:48.899418+00:00 app[web.1]: [27-Mar-2018 09:17:48 UTC]     PHP Warning:  require(/app/libraries/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open     stream: No such file or directory in /app/libraries/cms.php on line 36
2018-03-27T09:17:48.899730+00:00 app[web.1]: [27-Mar-2018 09:17:48 UTC]     PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required     '/app/libraries/vendor/autoload.php'     (include_path='.:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php') in /app/libraries/cms.php on     line 36
```

I looked at the structure of the download files and folders from Joomla, and the required file which is throwing the error is in my repository, so I don't understand why it would throw this error? See screenshot below for the structure of my files.

[image]

Any suggestions what to do?